# How to if-else in serverless

Tags: lambda, serverless

- I have one question,
  Now, i am handle serverless intergration with lambda, but config difference for multiple stage.
  so that, i am want to config environment for multiple mode. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

list step:

- install plugin: serverless-plugin-ifelse, link https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-ifelse
- in file serverless.yaml:

```
plugins:
 - serverless-plugin-ifelse
```

- blog `custom` in file serverless.yaml

```
custom:
  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${opt:stage, sls:stage}" == "dev"'
      Exclude:
        - provider.vpcEndpointIds
        - provider.apiGateway.resourcePolicy
    - If: '"${opt:stage, sls:stage}" == "pro"' 
      Exclude:
        - provider.logRetentionInDays
```